# Deleting from Oracle SQL table using 'inner join'

Tags: sql, oracle, join

SO I've searched high and low, trying other tips used on this forum to no avail.

So trying to delete using inner join in Oracle SQL Developer (v3.2.20.09)

Table I wish to delete from (Table1, column name Column1), where the data matches the column 'Column2' in 'Table2.

I know there are some differences between Oracle/Microsoft SQL, tried multiple queries such as below, with slight variation (using open/close brackets, inner joins, WHERE EXISTS, WHERE (select's).
TRY:

```
 delete from table2 where 
 exists (select column1 from table1);

 delete from table2, 
 inner join table1 on table2.column2 = table1.column1;
```

What are the problem(s) of the code that I wrote?

Comment: Consider using a [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm).  It contains a `DELETE` clause you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EXISTS` version would look like this:

```
delete from table2
where exists (select *
              from table1
              where table1.column1 = table2.column2);
```

Alternatively you can use an `IN` clause

```
delete from table2
where column2 in (select column1
                  from table1);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to delete from `table1`, then that's the table name that has to be used in the `delete` clause, not `table2`.

```
delete table1 t1
 where exists (select null
                 from table2 t2
                where t2.column2 = t1.column1)
```